# Set permission on edit to an item in Spreadsheet view depending on column values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, permissions, wss

I have a spreadsheet view with 50 items created in it. I have a status column for each item whose value could be Completed or In-Progress.
Here my requirement is to disable the edit link whose status is Completed for all users except the Admin users.

For example:

1.Item1   Completed

2.Item2   In-Progress

3.Item3   Completed

In the above example I want the Item1 and Item3 will have edit link enabled for Admin but disabled for all other users.

Can anyone please help me implement the requirement.

Comment: Custom javascript would also be able to do this, but I'm no coder...

Answer (score 0):

Using content type and  Information management policy settings you can do this.
Below is the link to article about this.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262490.aspx

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-EB501FE9-2EF6-4150-945A-65A6451EE9E9

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint 2010 platform workflow on the list and using Impersonation Step.

Create the workflow like the following, choose Strat workflow automatically when an item is created and Strat workflow automatically when an item is changed.

if the status equal Completed, Replace permission(set admin with full control permission and others with read permission):
[image]